# C#: System.Object vs Generics

Tags: c#, generics, object

I'm having a hard time understanding when to use Object (boxing/unboxing) vs when to use generics.

For example:

```
public class Stack 
{
    int position;
    object[] data = new object[10];
    public void Push (object o) { data[position++] = o; }
    public object Pop() { return data[--position]; }
}
```

VS.

```
public class Stack<T>
{ 
  int position; 
  T[] data = new T[100]; 
  public void Push(T obj)  {data[position++] = obj; }
  public T Pop() { return data[--position]; }
 }
```

Which one should I use and under what conditions? It seems like with the System.Object way I can have objects of all sorts of types currently living within my Stack. So wouldn't this be always preferable? Thanks!

Comment: See this related question too [why-not-always-use-generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040746/why-not-always-use-generics)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*Always* use generics! Using object's results in cast operations and boxing/unboxing of value-types. Because of these reasons generics are faster and more elegant (no casting). And - the main reason - you won't get `InvalidCastException`s using generics.

So, generics are faster and errors are visible at compile-time. `System.Object` means runtime exceptions and casting which in general results in lower performance (sometimes MUCH lower).

Comment: Except when you need multiple types. Try to do the ASP.NET Session object with generics.

Comment: Maybe something like List<object> ? :)

Comment: I mean Generics can be used every time, if you really need multiple types to be stored in your collection, you can simply use something like List<object>

Comment: That wouldn't avoid the (un)boxing.

Comment: So where does that leave "Always use generics" ?

Comment: I just meant that generics should be used every time even if you want to store multiple types - you can use List<object>. List<object> is generic collection :). Of course in this case you have to deal with casting and (un)boxing. I think we just didn't understood each other

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of ALWAYS... so there's absolutely no situation for me to use 'object'?

Comment: Here they want to say you can declare function as generic and pass your object parameters in it.

Comment: Like count(list<t>){do something} is the function and you will pass count (list<object>).

Comment: This way it will be both generic and support to list of different type of objects

Answer (score 16):

A lot of people have recommended using generics, but it looks like they all miss the point. It's often not about the performance hit related to boxing primitive types or casting, it's about getting the compiler to work for you.

If I have a list of strings, I want the compiler to prove to me that it will always contain a list of strings. Generics does just that - I specify the intent, and the compiler proves it for me.

Ideally, I would prefer an even richer type system where you could say for example that a type (even if it was a reference type) could not contain null values, but C# does unfortunately not currently offer that.

Answer (score 10):

While there are times when you will want to use a non-generic collection (think caching, for instance), you almost always have collections of homogenous objects not heterogenous objects.  For a homogenous collection, even if it is a collection of variants of base type or interface, it's always better to use generics.  This will save you from having to cast the result as the real type before you can use it.  Using generics makes your code more efficient and readable because you can omit the code to do the cast.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on what you need in the long run.

Unlike most answers here, I won't say "always use generics" because sometimes you do need to mix cats with cucumbers.

By all means, try to stick with generics for all the reasons already given in the other answers, for example if you need to combine cats and dogs create base class Mammal and have `Stack<Mamal>`.

But when you really need to support every possible type, don't be afraid to use objects, they don't bite unless you're mistreating them. :)

Answer (score 4):

With the `object` type, as you say you need to perform boxing and unboxing, which gets tedious very quickly. With generics, there's no need for that.

Also, I'd rather be more specific as to *what kind* of objects a class can work with and generics provides a great basis for that. Why mix unrelated data types in the first place? Your particular example of a stack emphasizes the benefit of generics over the basic `object` data type.

```
// This stack should only contain integers and not strings or floats or bools
Stack<int> intStack = new Stack<int>();
intStack.Push(1);
```

Remember that with generics you can specify interfaces so your class can interact with objects of many different classes, provided they all implement the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use generics when you want your structure to handle a single type.  For example, if you wanted a collection of strings you would want to instantiate a strongly typed List of strings like so:

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
```

If you want it to handle multiple types you can do without generics but you will incur a small performance hit for boxing/unboxing operations.

Comment: "Single type" is slightly misleading as the static type may be the base type for a number of types...

Answer (score 1):

Generics are always preferred if possible.

Aside from performance, Generics allow you to make guarantees about the types of objects that you're working with.

The main reason this is preferred to casting is that the compiler knows what type the object is, and so it can give you compile errors that you find right away instead of runtime errors that might only happen under certain scenarios that you didn't test.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are not golden hammer. In cases where your activity naturally is non-generic, use good old object. One such case - caching. Cache naturally can hold different types. I've recently seen this implementation of cache wrapper

```
void AddCacheItem<T>(string key, T item, int duration, ICacheItemExpiration expiration)
{
    . . . . . . .
    CacheManager.Add(cacheKey, item, ..... 
}
```

Question: what for, if `CacheManager` takes object?

Then there was real havoc in `Get`

```
public virtual T GetCacheItem<T>(string cacheKey)
{
    return (T)CacheManager.GetData(cacheKey); // <-- problem code
}
```

The problem above is that value type will crash.

I mended the method by adding this

```
public T GetCacheItem<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
```

Because I like idea of doing this

```
var x = GetCacheItem<Person>("X")?
string name = x?.FullName;
```

But I added new method, which will allow to take value types as well

```
public object GetCacheItem(string cacheKey)
```

The bottom line, there is usage for `object`, especially when storing different types in collection. Or when you have compositions where completely arbitrary and unrelated objects can exist when you need to consume them based on type.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pointed out advantages of generics over System.Object in general. However, one example of where System.Object is better than generics - how Microsoft implemented the new ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull in .NET 6+

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82227#issuecomment-1433175719

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull