# how to set constructor with List(of Class) parameter

Tags: vb.net, class

Given the scenario where I am building a wrapper for the data I pass to jquery datatables and I have for example, three Classes Orders, OrderDetails and Customers. In datatables, lists of objects are denoted by the variable name aoData, so to construct that I have to pass a List(Of someclass). Since I don't know which class until I pass it how do you do it? is There a GetType that takes the class name as a string? I couldn't find one.

```
 Public Class DataTablesWrapper
    Public Sub New(ByRef data As List(Of String))
        Me.aaData = data
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByRef data As List(Of some class depending on what data I want wrapped))
        Me.aoData = data
    End Sub
    Public Property aaData As List(Of String)
    Public Property aoData As List(Of some class depending on what data I want wrapped)
End Class
```

Comment: You could use [**generics**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx).

Comment: Why are you using `ByRef`?

Comment: Love anonymous down voters. Not exactly an easy thing to accomplish for relatively new programmers, thanks for those who assisted

Comment: @Dominic.. Originally I intended on manipulating "data", I am now using ByVal as thats not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w256ka79.aspx).

In your case it would look like this:

```
Public Class DataTablesWrapper(Of T)
    Public Sub New(ByRef data As List(Of T))
        Me.aaData = data
    End Sub

    Public Property aaData As List(Of T)
End Class
```

Creating your instance would then look like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim stringList As New List(Of String)({"foo", "bar"})      
    Dim tablesWrapper As New DataTablesWrapper(Of String)(stringList)
End Sub
```

You don't want to use `List(Of Object)` due to [this reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4424049/1603095).

Comment: I was trying to implement in this way but it didn't like List(Of T) due to my not adding that to the Class definition. Thank you