# Under what circumstances would boxing occur in modern C#?

Tags: c#, boxing

I'm trying to explain boxing to a junior colleague.

The canonical example seems to be `ArrayList`. For example:

- [Understanding Boxing and Unboxing in C#](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/csharp/understanding-boxing-and-unboxing-in-csharp)
- [Why do we need boxing and unboxing in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111905/50151)

But this has been superseded by `List<T>` from C# 2, when generics were introduced (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309699/50151)).

So, in the age of generics, under what circumstances would I find myself boxing values?

---

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm not asking whether it is still possible to use boxing. I'm asking why we would use boxing now that generics have made `ArrayList` obsolete.

---

**Edit 2:** I thought this was already clear, but I'm also not asking about the difference between an `ArrayList` and a `List<T>`. In fact, this question is entirely premised on the fact that I appreciate that generics mean we don't have to use an `ArrayList`, and we therefore don't need to box values in these circumstances.

Comment: If you do this: `object x = (object) 24;`, you've boxed.

Comment: Nothing has changed - conditions are the same

Comment: Please see my edit - I'm not asking how to box, or whether it's still possible. I'm asking why someone would box these days.

Comment: `ArrayList` is not the only class that takes object, `DataTable` and many others too. That's only .NET, there are many public interfaces that take or return objects or your own code might do too.

Comment: @Sinatr Not a dupe. The whole premise of my question is that I understand the difference between ArrayList and List<T>.

Comment: @TomWright -- That's totally different from the way your question was framed.  Your title says "when" not "why".

Comment: Then perhaps [object vs generics](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4424030/1997232).

Comment: interfacing. especially interfacing with annoyingly outdated third-party components.

Comment: The proof that boxing is still needed, is to find the first example where you can't solve the problem by another other (simple) means than through boxing. I haven't used boxing for the last ten years, and I've solved a lot of complicated stuff without needing it.

Comment: But...maybe some of the mechanisms I actually use uses boxing under the hood. Not sure there

Comment: The last time I needed it (outside of the framework): Walking recursivly through object properties with specific attributes. Rule of thumb: Always prefer generics, but sometimes it is not possible to do some task only with generics. Especialy if I think about DRY, I often end up using Reflection and Boxing.

Comment: You can box/unbox even with generics, using a `List<T>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boxing and unboxing is not something that you explicitly do; it is something that happens all the time whenever you have a `struct` in your hands and you are passing it to some receiver that expects an `object`.  So, consider this code:

```
public void SafeToString( Object a )
{
    if( a != null )
        return a.ToString();
    return "null";
}

SafeToString( 42 );
```

If you had said `42.ToString()` there would be no boxing, because 42 is known by the compiler to have a `ToString()` method, and `struct` cannot be subclassed, so the `ToString()` method that operates on 42 is known at compilation time.

However, when you say `SafeToString( 42 );` the 42 gets boxed into an object, which is passed to `SafeToString()`, which invokes `Object.ToString()`, which resolves to the boxing object's `ToString()`, which delegates to `int.ToString()`.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for this answer. Hope you don't mind, but I've quoted it in a blog I've just pubished: http://blog.tdwright.co.uk/2017/05/12/what-is-boxing-and-why-should-you-care/

Answer (score 2):

Generics is a good thing, but they aren't capable completely remove the necessity of dealing with boxing.

`ArrayList` is obsolete, right, but sometimes you still going to use `List<object>` when storing different types in one list (when only `Object` is something they have in common).

Another example generic methods. Again, they are good if you know type at compile-time, but what if you want something to work with any type? Good old `object` parameter and boxing (with casting) to the rescue.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I hope you don't mind, but I referenced this in a blog post I've just published: http://blog.tdwright.co.uk/2017/05/12/what-is-boxing-and-why-should-you-care/