# When should `Object` be used in C# 2.0 and newer? Do Generics replace all occurrences of Object?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-2.0

My coworker made the claim that there is never a need to use `Object` when declaring variables, return parameters, etc in .NET 2.0 and newer.

He went further and said in all such cases, a Generic should be used as the alternative.

Is there any validity to this claim?  Off the top of my head I use `Object` for locking concurrent threads...

Comment: Your coworker is being a little too dogmatic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: System.Object vs Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424030/c-system-object-vs-generics)

Comment: @vcsjones Imagine what it's like working on a project where lots of other similar assertions are being made.  Disproving them is exhausting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why-not-always-use-generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040746/why-not-always-use-generics)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generics do trump `object` in a lot of cases, but only where the type is **known**.

There are still times when you don't know the type - `object`, or some other relevant base type is the answer in those instances.

For example:

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance("Some type in an unreferenced assembly");
```

You won't be able to cast that result or maybe even know what the type is at compile time, so `object` is a valid use.

Your co-worker is generalising too much - perhaps point him at this question. Generics are great, give him that much, but they do not "replace" `object`.

Comment: Hmm, in this case can I use the constraint where T : Object?  (I never tried that)

Comment: An unconstrained generic type is always object - it is the lowest common denominator amongst the possible type arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`object` is perfect for a lock. Generics allow you to keep it typed appropriately. You can even constrain it to an interface or base class. You can't do that with `object`.

Consider this:

```
void DoSomething(object foo)
{
   foo.DoFoo();
}
```

That won't work without any casting. But with generics...

```
void DoSomething<T>(T foo) where T : IHasDoFoo
{
   foo.DoFoo();
}
```

With C# 4.0 and `dynamic`, you could deffer this to runtime, but I really haven't seen a need.

```
void DoSomething(dynamic foo)
{
   foo.DoFoo();
}
```

Comment: `object` is not really preferred. It's the simplest and readily available type, but lots of other types would work just as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Does it matter if the other type is value or reference?

Comment: You can only lock on a reference type.

Comment: Beyond the fact that people have been using `Object` for years, is there any reason that creating instances of type `Object` for locking would be better than using instances of a type named something like `MonitorLock` which was derived from object and contained no fields?  Are actual instances of `System.Object` ever used for any purpose which could not be fulfilled with such a derived type?

Answer (score 2):

When using interop with COM, you don't always have a choice... Generic don't really cater for the issues of interop.

`Object` is also the most lightweight option for a `lock`, as [@Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10754838/1583).

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is validity. A good breakdown has already been made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424030/c-system-object-vs-generics).

However, I cannot confirm if there is no instance where you will *never* use objects, but personally I do not use them and even before generics I avoided boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of counterexamples, including the one you mentioned, using an object for synchronisation.

Another example is the `DataSource` property used in databinding, which can be set to one of a variety of different object types.

Answer (score 0):

Broad counterexample: The System.Collections namespace is alive and well in .NET 4, no sign of deprecation or warning against its use on MSDN. The methods you find there take and return Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Inherent in the question are actually two questions:

1. When should storage locations of type `Object` be used

   When should instances of type `Object` be used

Storage locations of type `Object` must obviously be used in any circumstance where it will be necessary to hold references to instances of that type (since references to such instances cannot be held in any other type).  Beyond that, they should be used in cases where they will hold references to objects which have no single useful common base type.  This is obviously true in many scenarios using Reflection (where the type of an object may depend upon a string computed at run-time), but can also apply to certain varieties of collection which are populated with things whose type is known at compile time.  As a simple example, one could represent a hierarchical collection of `string` indexed by sequences of `int` by having each node be of type `Object`, and having it hold either a `String` or an `Object[]`.  Reading out items from such a collection would be somewhat clunky, since one would have to examine each item and determine whether it was an instance of `Object[]` or `String`, but such a method of storage would be extremely memory-efficient, since the only object instances would be those which either held the strings or the arrays.  One could define a `Node` type with a field of type `String` and one of type `Node[]`, or even define an abstract `Node` type with derived types `StringNode` (including a field of type `String`) and `ArrayNode` (with a field of type `Node[]`) but such approaches would increase the number of heap objects used to hold a given set of data.

Note that in general it's better to design collections so that the type of an object to be retrieved won't depend upon what's been shoved into the collection (perhaps using "parallel collections" for different types) but not everything works out that way semantically.

With regard to instances of type `Object`, I'm not sure there's any role they can fill which wouldn't be just as well satisfied by a sealed type called something like `TokenObject` which inherits from `Object`.  There are a number of situations where it is useful to have an object instance whose sole purpose is to be a unique token.  Conceptually, it might have been nicer to say:

```
TokenObject myLock = new TokenObject;
```

than to say

```
Object myLock = new Object;
```

since the former declaration would make clear that the declared variable was never going to be used to hold anything other than a token object.  Nonetheless, common practice is to use instances of type `Object` in cases where the only thing that matters about the object is that its reference will be unique throughout the lifetime of the program.