# Overuse of Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

what do people think of the usage of Generics when no real benefit is apparant. Below is an example snippet of code which is similar to code I work on and I am trying to determine what benefit if any is gained from the use of generics.

```
   public void DoSomething<Request>(Request request)
    {

        if (request == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }


        if (Request is ISomeInterface)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        else
        {
        DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
```

Why would you not just use Object?

Comment: You would just use object, in that example.

Comment: its called `BuzzWord Compliant`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: System.Object vs Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424030/c-system-object-vs-generics)

Comment: Why not use generics, do you want to save typing? I'd also speculate that the generic method could be more easily optimised by the compiler.

Comment: I want to know what benefit is gained from using generics in the above example

Comment: Why is this not a real question? Voting to reopen. In this one case, there is no benefit, and personally I like use `System.Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from : [C#: System.Object vs Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424030/c-system-object-vs-generics)

> Using object == cast operations and boxing/unboxing of value-types.
>   Because of these reasons generics are faster and more elegant (no
>   casting). And - the main reason, you won't get "InvalidCastException"
>   using generics
>
> So, generics == speed and compile-time errors. Object == runtime
>   exceptions,lower speed (sometimes MUCH lower)